# a problem about Lp space and Holder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If for any $g$ in $L^q$, $fg$ is in $L^1$, prove that $f$ is in $L^p$.
$p>1$, $p$ and $q$ are conjugate.
It is sort of an inverse version of Holder inequality.
We are considering Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Any assumptions on the underlying measure space? It is wrong at least if the measure space has infinite atoms (take $f$ the be the characteristic function of one). I am not sure if σ-finiteness is required. Or is it just Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen just Lebesgue measure in $R^n$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the closed graph theorem. By assumption, the map $g\mapsto fg$ is an everywhere defined linear map $L^q\to L^1$. To see that the graph is closed, assume that $g_n\to g$ in $L^q$ and $fg_n\to h$ in $L^1$. There is a subsequence with $g_n\to g$ a.e. and $fg_n\to h$ a.e., and these imply $fg=h$ a.e.

Now the map is bounded by the closed graph theorem. Can I ask you to take it from there? It should be enough to use the consequence that $g\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fg\,dx$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^q$.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't studied the closed graph theorem before. I am just learning some real analysis. Can you use another method?

Comment: I expect this can be done using more elementary methods, but I don't have any time to think of one right now, sorry. Hopefully someone else can pitch in.

Comment: As you may have noticed, this question has been asked before. There is a more elementary answer over at the duplicated.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Pick any $f\not \in L^p$ and let $g=0$.

Maybe, you need some condition about $g\not = 0$ a.e. ?

Comment: “For any” in the question must be taken to mean “for all”, not “for some” as you seem to have understood it.